# Identity theft. Accessing my Facebook page

Tags: facebook-privacy

I experienced identity theft. My credit card was used numerous times. Reported to CC company and police. My Facebook page lists another city than where I live on the weather log. I change it daily. It's back to another city the next morning Credit card company said all my charges were done between 1 and 5 AM. Can I get help to identify who is accessing my Facebook page?

Comment: You need to contact Facebook. If it's necessary to try to find the person who hacked your account will require the involvement of the police and a court order; Facebook will not just give you the information.

Comment: Thanks! How do I contact Facebook? I already filed a police report on the identity theft and they have the thief's name.

Comment: Start here: https://www.facebook.com/help/131719720300233

Comment: Good luck getting any support from Facebook. And as far as the police goes, all you may get from them is a required police report so you can claim some insurance or CC reports. Don't expect any arrests or ever finding out who did that.

Answer (score 1):

Please, do follow the "secure your account" procedures outlined in Facebook's security settings. The section where you terminate other active sessions is of particular importance. Also, be sure to activate "login approvals", it's a poor man's 2FA and half the time expects codes from a mobile app instead of SMSs but it's better than nothing.

In its efforts to create behavioral profiles, Facebook tends to "creep" from app to app, since it's actually convenient to use Facebook login for different services around the web, however that makes it easy to inadvertantly grant access to apps you that effectively overreach their intended purpose and can create backdoors to services unrelated to your leisure social catching up with friends.

So, do review and possibly revoke access to any apps active on your Facebook account (it's part of the secure your account procedure) you may be surprised at the level of access one grants "casually" to some applications (for example providing enough information to authenticate as yourself via social engineering: your phone number, home address, mother's maiden name, pets names,close friends names, odd nicknames, they may be available through your FB account, and are popular choices for "security questions" at other institutions, like credit unions.)

If the access is ongoing as you describe, a resourceful miscreant could even exploit your real friends and acquaintances, asking them for details "offline" via messenger, impersonating you of course.